# Adding multiple children in a tree using java

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I need to make an hierarchical structure which will be having  multiple children and these children further can have multiple children. So, I'm implementing it using tree but I'm stuck with it's implementation.

The structure I need to make from data is like:

```
class Node<T>
{
private T id;
private T description;
private T name;
private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();
private Node parent=null;

// then set and get methods

}
```

Children can have children

```
{  
   "ORGANIZATION":[  
      {  
         "   id":101,
         "category_name":"Organization 1",
         "description":" ",
         "WING ":[  
            //this is the category children which can also be a subcategory            {  
               "id":122,
               "category_name":"wing 1",
               "description":"",
               "FLOOR":[  
                  {  
                     "id":111,
                     "category_name":"floor 1"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "id":555,
               "category_name":"wing 2",
               "description":""
            },
            {  
               "id":222,
               "category_name":"wing 3",
               "description":""
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":11111,
         "category_name":"organization 2",
         "description":"",
         "WING":[  
            {  
               "id":4545,
               "category_name":"wing 1",
               "description":""
            },
            {  
               "id":252,
               "category_name":"wing 2",
               "description":"",
               "FLOOR":[  
                  {  
                     "id":131,
                     "category_name":"floor 1",
                     "description":""
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "id":2526,
               "category_name":"Wing 3 ",
               "description":"",
               "FLOOR":[  
                  {  
                     "id":87,
                     "category_name":"floor 2",
                     "description":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":565,
                     "category_name":"floor 3",
                     "description":"",
                     "ROOM":[  
                        // here is an example of a child that is a sub-category also                        {  
                           "id":555,
                           "category_name":"room 1",
                           "description":""
                        },
                        {  
                           "id":584,
                           "category_name":"room 2",
                           "description":""
                        },
                        {  
                           "id":77,
                           "category_name":"room 3",
                           "description":""
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm stuck with the class Node and I don't know how to implement it. So, Is there any implementation to form this structure? And what other functions i can add in my class Node.
Help me out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your solution, you're not very far at all. First observation is that `id`, `description` and `name` are all of different data types. I would not try to use generics here, as I believe they are a waste. In particular, you know `id` will be an [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), `description` will be a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), and `name` will be a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Using type `T` in this sense will only confuse you, as your problem doesn't fit the use case for [Java generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) (based on what has been presented).

Methods, outside of your standard [Java Bean methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans), would likely be `addChild(Node child)` and `isLeaf()`.

**`addChild(Node child)`**

This function will take in a node and add it to `children`. The purpose of this function is to simplify adding a node to the `children` list and will ensure that you don't have to work with lists externally to the class.

**`isLeaf()`**

This function will take a particular node and determine if it the leaf of the tree (that is, it would return a [Boolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) value). If you plan on operating on this tree to perform various algorithms, your code will become much simpler if you can call `node.isLeaf()` in place of `node.getChildren().size() == 0`. I have found this to be a good use of encapsulation in my code.

**Consider a builder pattern**

From my experience, I have found the [builder pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/builder-pattern-in-java/) to be incredibly helpful as far as code readability is concerned. Regardless if you chose to implement it here or not, it is something you will likely encounter in the future.

Comment: Yes, I have created that class but i don't know how to use these methods to generate such a structure i shared from flat data. I'm getting from my entity(table). I'm not able to model data in that format using class Node.Can u help me out?

Comment: You need to determine what your partition is. Ultimately, moving from a flat list into a tree would indicate some recursive relationship in the data itself. What justifies one row in your table to be a child of another? Once you find this, building a hierarchical structure is a bit more straight forward.

Comment: I found out the partition which is parentId,but I tried to make that tree structure by using iterations but it didn't help me. So recursion is going to be used here. But after adding 2 nodes I'm stuck at calling the same method for adding further nodes.

Comment: Recursion is definitely the way to go, especially if you don't know what your depth limit is in advance. Some business applications that leverage this type of thing (moving from a flat list of products to a hierarchy, for example), already have this predetermined. Also, your partition is typically some sort of property that would indicate a parent / child relationship needs to be established. This largely will depend on your requirements.

Comment: When writing a recursive algorithm, determine what your base case is, then what your recursive case is. This is why determining what your partition element, while the data is in a flat list is important. Based on that partition element, you should be able to determine what the leafs are.

Comment: Can you suggest some good links to study such examples of recursion.? This recursion is a tree which is having json objects into other json objects.

Comment: I have a few sources, however most of them are theoretical. I learned recursion through academia. These will take quite a bit of time, struggle, and most of all, practice. The biggest thing for me with recursion is that I unit test the heck out of it. My recommendation would be Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (https://web.mit.edu/alexmv/6.037/sicp.pdf). Just be warned, this is a serious study. I promise you, if you get through it though, you'll be quite comfortable with regards to recursive techniques (and much more).